# How is 's/he' pronounced? Do we say 'She or he should ..." or "He or she should ..."?

Tags: pronunciation, singular-they

How is 's/he' pronounced? Do we say 'She or he should ..." or "He or she should ..."?

Ex.: When a person applies for a job, s/he should always bring a resume.

Comment: However you like.

Comment: Again, ***show your research,*** since a dictionary is easy to look up. [ODO on s/he](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/s/he): "A written representation of **‘he or she’** used as a neutral alternative to indicate someone of either sex" (my emphasis). How does that not answer the question?

Comment: I don't get it. Does it mean transgender 'he/she'? Doesn't make much sense, and that.

Comment: Wow! One year suspended.  And to think I was going to warn whippoorwill that he was risking it.

Comment: The original question remains unanswered. Let us say that we are reading aloud a text which contains "s/he". What exactly is it that we are expected to vocalize? Are we to say aloud "he or she"? That is no pronunciation of "s/he", but if it is the case that we are expected to say "he or she", a proper answer rather than a dismissal would have to  explain that "s/he" is not pronounced, but is vocalized as "he or she".

In real life, s/he is always (IME) vocalized as "she or he", or simply as "she", sounding the same as the "new" gender-neutral pronoun.

Comment: @bobro I would posit that anyone who writes **s/he** is cutting corners, attempting to save space, time and characters. It is obviously an abbreviation,  *s/he* stands for *she or he*, or *he or she*; it doesn't matter which order you say the pronouns. The day somebody actually says: *es slash he* is the day I will feel abbreviation (road) rage.

Answer (score 2):

I’m pretty sure that *sh/e* is pronounced /ðeɪ/ in English.

However, the more-inclusive version, *sh/e/it*, has a rather more vulgar pronunciation. But that’s what political correctness gets you: vulgarity.

Comment: How is that vulgar? It would be the same pronunciation as 'Shiite'. This one is throwing me for a loop (very difficult).

Comment: @whipoorwill No, the PC version sounds like /ʃɪt/.

Comment: Can we answer questions without editorializing and being crude?

Comment: I don't know what kind of history you have with this user, but the effect I'm getting is that while browsing this SE I'm seeing random nastiness directed at anyone who tries to use gender neutral compounds because "political correctness gets you vulgarity", and that's unprofessional and unwelcoming.

Comment: @Yamikuronue We already have “a gender-neutral compound” in English, and have for 700 years.  It’s called *they*.  As for the user, please see [their posting history](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/40068/whippoorwill) for more understanding. If you have a matter to bring up on meta, you are encouraged to do so.

Comment: All I'm saying is, be nice: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: @Yamikuronue After the first 80 or 90 closed questions from [that user](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/40068/whippoorwill), one gets tired of seeing them posting more of the same. In the face of that, a little humor is the best I have to offer. I’m sorry you did not appreciate the humor; others did.

Answer (score 2):

I recall at university there was an (achingly politically correct) S/he Society, whose members prounounced it *Shehe*. But outside such specific contexts, you will always have to decide which pronoun you wish to use for a singular person of unspecified sex: *he, he or she,* singular *they*? *S/he* is a written version of the second, and as such is to most people vaguely unsatisfactory but not obnoxious.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, as "he/she" (slash is not vocalized) or "he or she". For whatever reason, it sounds strange to my (American) ears to say "she or he", despite the order that it was written in.

Oxford dictionaries agrees: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/s/he lists the definition as "A written representation of ‘he or she’ ", though the "pronounce this" button goes with "he she".